# Making Perl CPAN's Pg module work on Amazon's AWS server

Tags: postgresql, perl, amazon-web-services

I´m trying to port a Perl legacy software to Amazon's AWS servers, but I keep running on problems when trying to make all the components I need work.

Currently, I have Perl up and running (version 5.16.3), and PostgreSQL (9.2.18) as my database with no problems. They both run fine separately, but I simply can't make them work together.

This legacy software uses [Pg](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pg) library (I'm not referring to [DBD::Pg](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Pg), just [Pg](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pg)). However, I'm not able to run a script that references that specific library. I get the following error:

> `Can't locate loadable object for module Pg in @INC (@INC contains:  /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /var/www/cgi-bin) at /var/www/cgi-bin/teste.pl line 8.`

After some research, I understand that I'm somehow missing a dependency that `Pg` requires to work properly. I opened Pg.pm script to check which what it uses, and tried to import those through CPAN as well.

I managed to import `Exporter` and `Carp` successfully through `cpan` but `DynaLoader` simply won't install - apparently it needs to be compiled??

What do I need to do to properly install `Pg`?

Comment: You probably need the header files of the libpg library to compile the XS components.

Comment: @Sinar-Ünür  being completely honest, I just ran the command line to install Perl. I had no idea DynaLoader was already there, or I wouldn't have tried to install it again.

Comment: My God, how can I have missed that?? My bad @SinanÜnür .
BTW, I confirmed that DynaLoader was already installed, and that was the cause of the error I was getting - there was nothing else to be installed/updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used [Pg](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pg), so let's try on my ArchLinux install.

```
$ curl -O https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/ME/MERGL/pgsql_perl5-1.9.0.tar.gz
$ tar xvf pgsql_perl5-1.9.0.tar.gz
$ cd pgsql_perl5-1.9.0
$ perl Makefile.PL
$ perl Makefile.PL 
Configuring Pg
Remember to actually read the README file !
please set environment variables POSTGRES_INCLUDE and POSTGRES_LIB
```

So, if you installed `Pg`, you had to have set those variables. Simplest would be to install your chosen distro's package for those libraries. On ArchLinux, the following command installs them for me:

```
$ sudo pacman -S postgresql-libs
```

Then:

```
$ POSTGRES_INCLUDE=/usr/include POSTGRES_LIB=/usr/lib perl Makefile.PL 
Configuring Pg
Remember to actually read the README file !
OS: linux
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Pg
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
```

The build works but I can't test because I do not have a Postgresql instance to connect to. However, this works:

```
$ perl -I blib/lib -I blib/arch -e 'use Pg; print "ok\n"'
ok
```

Note the `-I` switches above would not have been necessary had I chosen to install this module that was last updated 17 years ago.

Comment: Your solution wasn't perfect but pointed me on the right path. First, I'm not sure if the variables POSTGRES_INCLUDE and POSTGRES_LIB were not set properly when the script was first imported, but when I did it again with your parameters it worked just fine.
However, the error still occurred, this time because of some Postgres dependencies that were missing (notably libpq-fe.h ) and because GCC was not installed. After importing the missing .h and installing GCC, the import was succesfull.